# Task OnDisconnected in SignalR slow response

Tags: signalr

I use SignalR with window application. I have override 3 tasks:
OnConnected(),OnReconnected() and OnDisconnected()

for OnConnected(), it response fast.
but for OnDisconnected response very slow.
Any option to set time or any solution?
I hope this questions make sense! :)

Comment: public override Task OnConnected()
  {
   users.Add(Context.ConnectionId);
   return base.OnConnected();
  }
  public override Task OnReconnected()
  {
   users.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
   return base.OnReconnected();
  }
  public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
  {
   users.Remove(Context.ConnectionId);
   return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
  }

Comment: Do you want to change  disconnection time ?

Comment: yes. like if it has default timeout or delay time. i wait almost 1 minute.

Comment: it is very long time and it look not good for using also. do you know how to change or set it?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you want to change default disconnection time of SigalR, but in most of the case's default values are enough.

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // Wait a maximum of 30 seconds (Default value) after a transport connection is lost before raising the
            // Disconnected event to terminate the SignalR connection.
      int disconnectTimeout = 30;
      GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(disconnectTimeout);
    }
```